# Print specific nested value items

Tags: dictionary, printing, nested

I have a nested dictionary where i want to create defs which will print in table format (headers: Console, controller, etc) the stock in stuff of specifically each device.

For example I have a def assigned on a button (for each device(NEs,SNES, XBOX OG etc etc) called def print_(console's name*)_items() which I want to print in table format only the stuff which are nested in it. For DreamCast only the dreamCast etc:

My dict is below:

*warehouse = {"Nintendo":{"NES":{"Console":1,"Controller":1,"Controller parts":1},
"SNES":{"Console":0,"Mouse":1,"Hyperkin mouse":1,"Controller 3rd party":3},
"N64":{"Console black":1,"Console blue Jap":2,"Parts of console black":1},
"Wii":{"Console white":4,"Console black":1,"Console mini":1,"Controller white":2,"Nunchuck white":6,"Controller black":3,"Nunchuck black":2,"Steering wheel":2,"Controller pro black":1},
"Wii U":{},
"Switch":{},
"Gameboy":{"Console DMG":11,"Console pocket":0,"Console color":0,"Console advance":1,"Console SP":0},
"DS":{"Console DS original":2,"Console DS lite":21,"Console DSi":1,"Console DSi XL":2,"Console 2DS":1,"Console 3DS":6,"Console 3DS XL":2,"Parts of 3DS XL":1}},
"Sega":{"Master system":{"Console":0},
"Mega drive":{"Console":0,"Parts of console":1,"Controller":3,"Parts of controller":1},
"DreamCast":{"Console":1,"Controller":1}},
"Sony":{"PS 1":{"Console fat":4,"Parts of console fat":2,"Console one":2,"Controller dogbone":6,"Parts of controlled dogbone":1,"Controller Dualshock grey":2,"Parts of controller dualshock grey":1,"Controller PS one":1,"Controller 3rd party":7,"Gcon gun":1},
"PS 2":{"Console fat":23,"Parts of console fat":5,"Console slim":5,"Parts of console slim":9,"Controller black":57,"Parts of controller black":37,"Controller silver":12,"Camera silver":3,"Controller 3rd party":31},
"PS 3":{"Console fat":2,"Console slim":4,"Parts of console super slim":1,"Controller black":35,"Parts of controller black":9,"Controller 3rd party":17,"Camera":1},
"PS 4":{"Console fat":2,"Console slim":3,"Controller black":27,"Controller red":1,"Controller purple":1,"Controller blue":1}},
"Microsoft":{"OG":{"Console":0,"Parts of console":3,"Parts of controller":3,"Controller 3rd party":3},
"Xbox 360":{"Console white":5,"Controller white wired":13,"Controller white wireless":10,"Controller black wired":2,"Controller black wireless":21,"Camera":1},
"Xbox one":{"Console":0,"Parts of console":1,"Camera":1,"Controller 3rd party":7}},
"Retro Bit":{"Super retro trio":{"Console":1}}}*

I tried to use a for loop in def such as:
def print_DreamCast_items():
for k, v in warehouse.items():  //but here i need to specify from which console I want to print.

I am beginner so please not yell at me..